# ERROR/AndroidRuntime(631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main, ERROR/AndroidRuntime(631): java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android

I'm developing a Baby Names app. I'm getting runtime exception while developing the App. Here is some part of the log file.

```
11-06 01:37:00.970: WARN/dalvikvm(631): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-06 01:37:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 01:37:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(631): java.lang.StackOverflowError
11-06 01:37:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(631): at balu.android.CommonNameTable.<init>(CommonNameTable.java:59)
11-06 01:37:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(631): at balu.android.CommonNameTable.<init>(CommonNameTable.java:59)
```

The functionality of App is going to be like this.

1. Select activity contains a menu, having the following items.

   > Common names
   >   Uncommon names
   >   Names popular in a specific city

https://github.com/Balu-Varanasi/BabyNamesApp/blob/master/src/balu/android/Select.java - is the link to the Select Activity.

2.When the user selects - "Common names" -

a new Activity will be launched. I contains a ListView, of all the names from CommonNameTable in the SQLite database. In the constructor of the table, I tried to insert records from the file "commonnames.txt". Here is the links to the classes I have written.

I think this is the source of the problem.

https://github.com/Balu-Varanasi/BabyNamesApp/blob/master/src/balu/android/CommonNameTable.java
https://github.com/Balu-Varanasi/BabyNamesApp/blob/master/src/balu/android/CommonNames.java

Could you please help me in fixing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the CommonNameTable's constructor recursively, Please remove the line indicated below

```
public CommonNameTable(Context ctx) {

    this.mCtx = ctx;
    //REMOVE THIS LINE
    CommonNameTable commonNameTable = new CommonNameTable(this.mCtx);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Is it enough to open the table as this.open() and this.close() public CommonNameTable(Context ctx) {
    
      this.mCtx = ctx;
 
      this.open();
       
 ...
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
         String[] temp;

         strLine = strLine.trim();
         temp = strLine.split("\\s+");
         
         this.createCommonName(temp[1], temp[0]);
 ...
      
      this.close();
}